# Adding two multidimensional arrays and print the resulting multi-array in a new list JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to add the numbers inside of two multi-arrays together and print it out in another multi dim.-array, here's the code i've got so far but it shows this error "incompatible types: double cannot be converted to double[][]" every time, can anyone please help?

```
import java.util.*;
public class AddMatrices
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  double[][] list1 = new double [3][3];
  double[][] list2 = new double [3][3];
  double[][] list3 = new double [3][3];

  System.out.println("Enter your first 3-by-3 matrix row by row:");
  for(int row = 0; row<3; row++){
     for(int col = 0; col<3; col++){
        list1[row][col] = scan.nextDouble();
     }
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Enter your second 3-by-3 matrix row by row:");
  for(int row2 = 0; row2<3; row2++){
     for(int col2 = 0; col2<3; col2++){
        list2[row2][col2] = scan.nextDouble();
     }
  }
  System.out.print("The sum of these two matrices is: ");
  for(int row3 = 0; row3<3; row3++){
     for(int col3 = 0; col3<3; col3++){
        list3[row3][col3] = addMatrix(list1[row3][col3],list2[row3][col3]);
        System.out.println(list3[row3][col3] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
 }
 public static double[][] addMatrix(double[][] a, double[][] b){
 double[][] output = new double [a.length][a[0].length];
 for(int row = 0; row<a.length; row++){
     for(int col = 0; col<a[row].length; col++){
        output[row][col] = a[row][col] + b[row][col];
     }
  }
  return output;
 }
}
```

Updated code(it works yay!Thanks a lot guys):

```
import java.util.*;
public class AddMatricies
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean rep = false;

  while(rep == false){

  double[][] list1 = new double [3][3];
  double[][] list2 = new double [3][3];
  double[][] list3 = new double [3][3];

  //asks for the first matrix
  System.out.println("Enter your first 3-by-3 matrix row by row:");
  for(int row = 0; row<3; row++){
     for(int col = 0; col<3; col++){
        list1[row][col] = scan.nextDouble();
     }
  }
  //asks for the second matrix
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Enter your second 3-by-3 matrix row by row:");
  for(int row2 = 0; row2<3; row2++){
     for(int col2 = 0; col2<3; col2++){
        list2[row2][col2] = scan.nextDouble();
     }
  }
  //add both matrices
  System.out.println("The sum of these two matrices is: ");
  for(int row3 = 0; row3<3; row3++){
     for(int col3 = 0; col3<3; col3++){
        list3 = addMatrix(list1,list2);    //where the main changes are
        System.out.print(list3[row3][col3] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.print("Would you like to go again? ");
  String dec = scan.next();
  if(dec.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
  rep = false;
  }
  else
  rep = true;
  }
}
//the method for adding both matrices
public static double[][] addMatrix(double[][] a, double[][] b){
double[][] output = new double [a.length][a[0].length];
for(int row = 0; row<a.length; row++){
     for(int col = 0; col<a[row].length; col++){
        output[row][col] = a[row][col] + b[row][col];
     }
  }
  return output;
}
}
```

Comment: I bet this is the line:  list3[row3][col3] = addMatrix(list1[row3][col3],list2[row3][col3]); your addMatrix is returning an array that you try to push into a double value...

Comment: Next time, please include the complete compiler error message. It is tedious to figure out the exact line containing the syntax error.

Comment: Futhermore, the addMatrix takes array as input so no good passing double value... "double cannot be converted to double[][]"

Comment: @PetterFriberg You gave an insight of how to solve the problem haha I still used the method, just had to tinker a bit on how to print the whole thing out, thanks!

Comment: @T. Hry, great solving your own problems is always best.... have fun

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid using the method addMatrix, because it doesn't add value to the code and generates the problems. The code should look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class AddMatrices
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  double[][] list1 = new double [3][3];
  double[][] list2 = new double [3][3];
  double[][] list3 = new double [3][3];

  System.out.println("Enter your first 3-by-3 matrix row by row:");
  for(int row = 0; row<3; row++){
     for(int col = 0; col<3; col++){
        list1[row][col] = scan.nextDouble();
     }
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Enter your second 3-by-3 matrix row by row:");
  for(int row2 = 0; row2<3; row2++){
     for(int col2 = 0; col2<3; col2++){
        list2[row2][col2] = scan.nextDouble();
     }
  }
  System.out.print("The sum of these two matrices is: ");
  for(int row3 = 0; row3<3; row3++){
     for(int col3 = 0; col3<3; col3++){
        list3[row3][col3] = list1[row3][col3]+list2[row3][col3];
        System.out.println(list3[row3][col3] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
 }

}
```